# Use array_filter in GET

Tags: php, get, doctrine

I have some problems with `GET` request. This request has two parameters to filter:

```
$app->get('/api/v1/provider/{destination}/{weight}', function ($request, $response, $args) {

   $em = getEntityManager();
   $destination = $em->getRepository(Transport::class)->findByDestination($args['destination']);
   $weight = $em->getRepository(Transport::class)->findByWeight($args['weight']);

     $provider_filter = array_filter($destination, function ($data) {
        return $data->weight == $weight;    
    });

    return $response->withJson($provider_filter);
});
```

For example , if I write `$dato->weight == 3` instead of `$dato->weight == $weight`, I get correct result. The problem is in the variable `$weight`, due to which  `$weight` I get the error: `Undefined variable: weight`. The variable  `$weight` is defined outside the array_filter. Nevertheless, if I defined `$weight` inside the array I can't get the weight because of the error: `Undefined variable: args`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your variables inside [closure/anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) you need to pass them as `use($weight)`  like

```
$provider_filter = array_filter($destination, function ($data) use($weight) {
    return $data->weight == $weight;    
});
```